# python3 - updated global variable value not used instead old value is used

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to update a variable, say x, in an imported module and then trying to use the updated variable x in other variable, say y, but y uses the old value of x instead of the new value. Please help provide some pointers to make it work!

My intention is to use a py file to list all global variable which I can use them in other py files. I could update a global variable and use it but not sure how to use an updated global variable in other variables.

### Sample code:

**a.py:**

```
var1 = 0
var2 = var1 + 1
```

**b.py:**

```
import a

def update_var():
    a.var1 = 10
    print("Updated var1 is {}".format(a.var1))
    print("var2 is {}".format(a.var2))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_var()
```

**Output:**

```
Updated var1 is 10
var2 is 1
```

**Expected Output:**

Since i am updating var1 to 10, i am expecting that the updated value be used in var2

```
Updated var1 is 10
var2 is 11
```

Comment: Related/Dupe: [Updating a parameter's value doesn't update the result of the function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49587299)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the inputs from @GPhilo and my personal experiences i came up with below working solutions, guess solution 2 is more pythonic.

Solution 1:

a.py:

```
class Globals:

def __init__(self, value):
    self.var1 = value
    self.var2 = self.var1 + 1
```

b.py:

```
from a import Globals

def update_var():
    globals_instance = Globals(10)
    print("Updated var1 is {}".format(globals_instance.var1))
    print("var2 is {}".format(globals_instance.var2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_var()
```

Output:

```
Updated var1 is 10
var2 is 11
```

Solution 2:

Change implementation of a.py as below"

a.py:

```
class Globals:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._var1 = value
        self.var2 = self._var1 + 1


    @property
    def var1(self):
        return self._var1


    @var1.setter
    def var1(self, value):
        self._var1 = value
```

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't work that way. When you `import` a module, the code in the module is executed. In your case, that means two variables are defined: `a.var1` with value `0` and `a.var2` with value `1`. If you then modify `a.var1`, you won't affect `a.var2`, its value was defined when you imported the module and it won't change unless you explicitly alter it.

Comment: thanks for you quick response. i observed this behavior. When i re-import, variables get reverted to original values. But how to over come this? How to make persistent changes to modules which have global variables? I have a use case where i will maintain all global variable in a separate file and few variable depend on other variable values, like the one in my sample code(var2 = var1 + 1). Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to not store global variables in a module, as you already saw that doesn't work as you'd like it to. If you have dependencies on the variables, you could define a `Globals` class that has properties (note: not fields, but actual properties) in which the setters take care of updating the related variables as needed. You could ten apply something similar to a Singleton pattern to generate only one instance of the class and pass the same instance where needed. Note that, depending on your specific use-case, this may or may not work.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to var2 being initialized only once whilst importing. 
The way around this would be to write a `getter` or and `update` function.

---

A possible getter function would be:

**a.py**

```
var1 = 0
var2 = var1 + 1

def getVar2():
    return var1 + 1
```

**b.py:**

```
import a

def update_var():
    a.var1 = 10
    print("Updated var1 is {}".format(a.var1))
    print("var2 is {}".format(a.getVar2()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_var()
```

---

A possible update function would be:

**a.py**

```
var1 = 0
var2 = var1 + 1

def updateVar2():
    var2 = var1+1
```

**b.py:**

```
import a

def update_var():
    a.var1 = 10
    a.updateVar2()
    print("Updated var1 is {}".format(a.var1))
    print("var2 is {}".format(a.var2()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_var()
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. But your solution cannot be used when there are many variables that depend on each other. like var2 = var1 +1, there can be many other variables that use var1, say var3 = var2 +1, var4 = var2 + var2 etc... Also the getter or update function just return some values but not update the module variables.